# How common is "biggety" in Southern and Midland US?

Tags: american-english, southern-white-vernacular-english

I recently stumbled upon the word [biggety](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biggety), meaning conceited or vain, and when I went to look it up, it seems the word is regional, which might explain why I'd never heard of it, except for one region it's supposedly used (Southern US) in is the region I've lived for over four decades.

So, how common is it in the Southern US? How common is it in Midland US?

Comment: New to me but sounds Southern. Sounds a lot like 'uppity' which is frowned upon these days, so maybe 'biggity' is a replacement?

Comment: @Mitch According to the OED, we have Joel Chandler Harris (author of the Uncle Remus stories) to thank for it: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/biggity_adj

Comment: I'm in New England and I've definitely heard it before, though it's uncommon.

Comment: I'm sure there is a data set with geolocation info that would make this an easy automated way to see. Sadly I don't know where that data set might be.

Comment: I think for a while researchers could use location-tagged Twitter data for this kind of thing, but Elon Musk stopped that.

Comment: I've maybe heard it once or twice, but its not common here in Upper Midwest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question that can be somewhat answered by automation. Take a corpus of text (gathered from some source) of reasonably large size (in order to be big enough to include appreciable amounts of the desired language phenomenon) and tagged with geolocation data (so that frequency of the phenomenon by location can be determined).

The usual source of a mix of formal and informal text (not speech but just written) that is geotagged is from the Twitter API.

There are problems with all aspects of this data source: the huge size of the population (of all tweets), [sampling by spread over an area is problematic](https://www.languagejones.com/blog-1/2014/12/24/the-problem-with-twitter-maps), the usual unknown of text vs speech.

Here is an [article from Quartz magazine about dude vs bro vs pal vs etc](https://qz.com/316906/the-dude-map-how-american-men-refer-to-their-bros), comparing the frequency of each on a US map.

That's the kind of comparison you're looking at.

But automation needs software, or at least someone who has gone through all the trouble and created a website for it.

I could only find one easy to use 'word frequency mapper'

[HomeArea](https://www.homearea.com/featured/regional-dialect/)

For a relatively common word, 'sassy', 15,787/billion you get the map:
[image: map of frequency of use of 'sassy' on Twitter around the US]
This looks reasonable... I have no preconceptions of the word sassy as far as regional dialect goes.

For the much rarer 'uppity' at 277/billion:
[image: map of frequency of use of 'uppity' on Twitter around the US]
This... seems weird to me. Why would Montana and Wyoming be a hotbed for the use of 'uppity' (a -very- Southern word). This makes me mistrust their corpus -and- their mapping software.

And now after all that, the target word:

[image: map of frequency of use of 'biggity' on Twitter around the US]

122/billion. So pretty rare. A rough description is that 'biggity' is more common in the south and especially Alabama/Mississippi but not particularly more or less common in the Midwest.

I wouldn't take this as any kind of absolute. The site doesn't give the time span when the tweets were collected. And really, the number is so low that local maxima or minima can't be reliably said to be predictive.

Also, in case anyone cares to do a quick project, [here is some Python code to make your own maps](http://jurgens.people.si.umich.edu/tutorials/Mapping_Word_Frequencies_on_Twitter_using_Python.html) with discussion of the interpolating algorithm that creates the color weights for an area based on point data.

Comment: Maybe my google-fu ain't great, so please feel free to look for/suggest other ways to do this (a link to a site that does this for you probably easiest).

Comment: This looks like an interesting strategy. Have you tried any of its variants? (_biget(t)y, biggaty, biggedy, biggety, biggidy, biggoty, bigit(t)y, bigot(t)y_)

Comment: @Heartspring Thanks...none of those had any hits... except for 'biggity'...update in a second.

Comment: I forgot to add this last time; [this](https://dare.wisc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1051/2016/04/biggityadjmap.png) is the map given by DARE. Doesn't really give frequency, but it at least gives a rough idea of where the word might be used.

Comment: @Heartspring Nice. Sort of corroborative (Kentucky is part of 'the South'). Still very low numbers to be confident.

Comment: Nice, that also explains why I haven't heard it. I grew up in Atlanta, and currently live in central VA. So, possibly _some_ of my more distant neighbors might use it, but no one I hang around.

Comment: Side note: 'uppity' should not be used by whites for Blacks. I can't tell if it can be used at all. So I'm not sure about 'biggity' (since it is new to me).

Comment: Also, I wonder what's going on in Colorado/Wyoming?

Comment: @BenHocking I don't think the maps are very reliable with such low data. It could be one person in Wyoming uses it a lot (and maybe moved there from the South?). There are lots of other real world circumstances (and just plain data anomalies) that could explain things (like the weird blob in Montana/Wyoming for 'uppity').

Comment: there are so many bots on twitter, I am not sure if their data can be trusted WRT word choice and usage.

Comment: @Yorik Yes, the reliability of the source of data is in question. We don't know the scale of the bots. Sometimes you gotta go with the source that's available and mitigate when you can.