# Are 'biggity' and 'briggity' kin?

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms, phonology, historical-change, southern-white-vernacular-english

<sub><sup>(Motivated by the question [*How common is "biggety" in Southern and Midland US?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613313/466641))</sup></sub>

---

The DARE entry for *briggity* has the following (edited):

> ***[briggity](https://dare.wisc.edu/words/quarterly-updates/quarterly-update-4/briggity/)***: (also *brickaty*, *brickety*, *brigaty*, *brigetty*, *briggaty*, *briggety*, *briggidy*, *briggoty*, *brigity*)    chiefly South Appalachian, adj.
> Restless, aggressive, “feisty”; hence n. *bricketiness*.

And for *biggity*, ohne 'r', also edited, has:

> *[**biggity**](https://dare.wisc.edu/words/quarterly-updates/quarterly-update-4/biggity-adj/)* (also *biget(t)y, biggaty, biggedy, biggety, biggidy, biggoty, bigit(t)y, bigot(t)y*) chiefly Southern- see [map](https://dare.wisc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1051/2016/04/biggityadjmap.png), adj.
> Exhibiting a sense of superiority or self-importance; arrogant, insolent, “uppity”; hence n. *biggitiness*.

Both entries have a number of quotations. The entry for *biggity* discusses a possible connection to 'bigoted', while the entry for *briggity* also includes:

> Perhaps a variant of *biggity* adj., but it is difficult to explain the supposed alteration. Differences of form and meaning, especially in earlier quotes, suggest independent origin with later assimilation to *biggity* adj.

My question is basically asking for details, alternate theories, or authoritative references about this claim. Etymologically and evolutionarily, what is the relationship between *biggity* and *briggity*? Is this a story of convergence or divergence with a beautiful phonological or historical explanation?

Comment: If they're not, someone should introduce them.

Comment: It says at your link for *briggity*: ”Differences of form and meaning ... suggest independent origin with later assimilation to *biggity*...” So, adopted kin?

Comment: FWIW, _OED_ doesn't have _briggity_. For _biggity_, _OED_ mentions _uppity_ as a possible parallel formation. _Briggity_ appears to be some arbitrary formation based on _biggity_, perhaps an eye dialect version.

Comment: It's interesting that (according to DARE) "biggity" first pops up in 1880 in Joel Chandler Harris's hugely popular Uncle Remus stories—a dozen years after the first cited occurrence (in DARE) of "brickety." Harris had a good ear, but I wonder whether he might not have either misheard "brickety" or attributed a mishearing or variant pronunciation of it to his characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first explanation of the meaning of "brickety" is by a "colored" woman named Harriet Hernandes from Spartanburgh, South Carolina, [testifying](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Report_Made_to_the_Two_Houses_of_Congres/rhtJAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22brickety%22&pg=PA590&printsec=frontcover) about the KKK on 10 July 1871:

> Q: Which one was it?
> A: I think it was Romeo.
> Q: Why?
> A: He was so brickety.
> Q: What do you mean by that?
> A: Fidgety-someone who wants to get into business and don't know how.
> Q: That you call brickety?
> A: Yes sir.
> Q: He got into your business that night?
> A: Yes sir; and I didn't like it much.
> Q: Why was he brickety?
> A: Because he jumped on top of me and beat me.
> ...
> A: [Now referring to Tine Martin] Fidgety ways, brickety ways
> ...
> A:...They all tried to be brickety [she goes on to describe violence by Tine Martin and family]

With the spelling "briggity" an early example is in the 1877 play [A Case for Divorce](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Case_for_Divorce/uxANAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22briggity%22&pg=RA1-PA23&printsec=frontcover) where, after an altercation starts, Mammy Lou says:

> Wha' fo' you making yo'self so briggity in de house of gentlefolks?

There is also an 1876 [example](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82014805/1876-08-08/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1770&sort=date&rows=20&words=briggity&searchType=basic&sequence=0&index=1&state=&date2=1963&proxtext=briggity&y=14&x=10&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) of "briggity" in the Wilmington, Delaware *Daily Gazette*, supposedly citing to the Atlanta *Constitution* newspaper, but it's so offensive I don't want to quote it.

For "biggity" the first etymological discussion is in the April 1881 [Schriber's Monthly](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Scribners_Monthly/bI0PAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=biggity%20books&pg=PA962&printsec=frontcover) at page 962. "Biggity" is defined as:

> big, pompous, inflated, proud

(seeming to imply biggity derives from "big")

Also, Mark Twain in the 1883 [Life on the Mississippi](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/245/245-h/245-h.htm):

> consequently the captains were very independent and airy—pretty 'biggity,' as Uncle Remus would say.

Overall, I would say that the original meanings of "brickety" and "briggity" were more negative and trouble making than "biggity".

On the other hand, in the 2 April 1885 [The Nation](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Nation/HfMxAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=biggity%20books&pg=PA279&printsec=frontcover), E. Alexander of the University of Tennessee, Knoxville wrote a letter to the editor saying that Tennessee folks don't say "brigaty", they say "biggity". The point of this letter is to criticize the language of Mary Murfree's 1884 book [In the Tennessee Mountains](https://www.google.com/books/edition/In_the_Tennessee_Mountains/8i5VAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22brigaty%22&pg=PA189&printsec=frontcover) which uses the word "brigaty" and ponders the origin of the word. Two weeks later J. B. Harrison wrote another letter to editor disagreeing with "Professor Alexander" saying that he or she has heard "brigaty" "as as often as the other form".

Comment: It looks as though [Andrew Cathcart, testifying 17 days after Harriet Hernandes, in Yorkville, South Carolina](https://books.google.com/books?id=IQxYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1596&dq=%22brickety%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUjdOay56CAxUjLX0KHdm2B8k4ChDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22brickety%22&f=false), also uses the term _brickety_.

Comment: Another early instance of "brickety" appears in the [_Richmond Dispatch_](https://virginiachronicle.com/?a=d&d=DD18740822.1.2&srpos=1&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-brickety-------) (August 22, 1874). And another appears in [_The American Stationer_](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nnc2.ark:/13960/t9x12vp40&seq=186&q1=brickety) (March 23, 1875), evidently repeating an item from the _Louisville Courier-Journal_.

Comment: @SvenYargs this March 1874 use of "brickety" also cites to a Courier-Journal https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86053573/1874-03-24/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1770&sort=date&rows=20&words=brickety&searchType=basic&sequence=0&index=9&state=&date2=1963&proxtext=brickety&y=12&x=12&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1